# Настройка apache2 + suEXEC

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Сервер

```
Ubuntu 14.04
```

Web - сервер

```
Apache 2.2.22
```

Активирован модуль suEXEC

```
a2enmod suexec
```

При выполнении команды

```
suexec -V
```

ошибка

```
Команда 'suexec' не найдена, возможно вы имели в виду:
Команда 'stexec' из пакета 'steptalk' (universe)
suexec: команда не найдена
```

А по мануалу должно быть 
Next, check which document root your Apache's suexec accepts:

```
# suexec -V
 -D AP_DOC_ROOT="/var/www"
 -D AP_GID_MIN=100
 -D AP_HTTPD_USER="www"
 -D AP_LOG_EXEC="/var/log/apache/suexec.log"
 -D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 -D AP_UID_MIN=100
 -D AP_USERDIR_SUFFIX="public_html"
```

Установил пакет

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-suexec-custom
```

В папке

```
/usr/lib/apache2
```

есть

```
modules  mpm-event  mpm-itk  mpm-prefork  mpm-worker  suexec
```

Команда

```
gitroot@gitserver:/usr/lib/apache2$ suexec -V
```

Возвращает ошибку

```
Команда 'suexec' не найдена, возможно вы имели в виду:
 Команда 'stexec' из пакета 'steptalk' (universe)
suexec: команда не найдена
```

Что это может быть?

Comment: *При выполнении команды* — а почему вы решили, что такая команда должна существовать?

Comment: В мануалах по настройке есть такая команда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если речь о [пакете](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apache2-suexec&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) *apache2-suexec-custom* или *apache2-suexec-pristine*, то, библиотека *suexec* не помещается в какой-нибудь каталог, обычно присутствующий в переменной `$PATH`, а располагается в каталоге `/usr/lib/apache2`.

для её «вызова» с опцией `-V` надо указывать полный путь. причём у рядовых пользователей нет прав на такой «вызов». его надо выполнять от имени пользователя *root*, либо напрямую:

```
# /usr/lib/apache2/suexec -V
```

либо, в случае рядового пользователя, которому доступен запуск программ от имени других пользователей, с помощью *sudo*:

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/apache2/suexec -V
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Все расно ошибка

Comment: запускайте команду так, как приведена: `sudo /usr/lib/apache2/suexec -V`. или, если вы уже запустили root-овую оболочку: `/usr/lib/apache2/suexec -V`

Comment: Вот что выдало-D SUEXEC_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/apache2/suexec/
 -D AP_GID_MIN=100
 -D AP_LOG_EXEC="/var/log/apache2/suexec.log"
 -D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 -D AP_UID_MIN=100 А почему вывод так сильно отличается от того что я в аопросе в качестве примера дал?

Comment: так настроен установленный вами пакет.

Comment: Во всех мануалах по умолчанию suexec -V выводит практически одно и тоже. У меня же совсем не то. Никак не могу найти толкового мануала именно по настройке suexec

Comment: по поводу опции `-V`: [this option displays the compile options of suexec](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/suexec.html). если вас категорически не устраивают опции, с которыми собрана библиотека *suexec* в установленном вами пакете, вы всегда можете пакет пересобрать.